# Android: How to open a Fragment with Navigation Graph without replacing the current Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack

I am wondering if there is a way to add another fragment to the screen without replacing the old one with the Navigation Graph.

I want to do this because the new fragment will just be open for a bit just to check some details and when the user returns to the previous fragment, I want them to be in the same spot they left off.

I have read around but I couldn't find one that does it without replacing the original. I have tried to just add it to the `nav_graph_fragment` which I try to do this in the newFrag() function in the CurrentFragment section but it doesn't work.

**Main Activty**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
    private val navController by lazy {
        (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment).navController
    }
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.mainToolBar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, null)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu_bar, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        if (item.itemId == navController.currentDestination?.id)
            return true
        return item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

**Main Activity xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/appbar"
        android:id="@+id/mainToolBar"/>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mainToolBar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**CurrentFragment**

```
class CurrentFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var currentFragmentViewModel: CurrentFragmentViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: CurrentFragmentBinding
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.current_fragment, container, false)
        currentFragmentViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CurrentFragmentViewModel::class.java)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.viewmodel = currentFragmentViewModel

        binding.accountButton.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("TEST", "button clicked")
            newFrag()
        }

        return binding.root
    }


    // Here is where I am trying to open the new fragment
    private fun newFrag() {
        val newFrag = Fragment()
        val transaction: FragmentTransaction = parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.hide(this)
        transaction.add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, newFrag).commit()

    }

}
```

**Nav Graph**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.example.app.ui.main.MainFragment"
        android:label="MainFragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_currentFragment"
            app:destination="@id/currentFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/currentFragment"
        android:name="com.example.app.ui.search.CurrentFragment"
        android:label="currentFragment" >
        
    </fragment>
```

Comment: `when the user returns to the previous fragment, I want them to be in the same spot they left off.` even with replace+addToBackStack, you should be at the same spot where you left off. If not, then your state restoration is bugged for some reason, potentially missing IDs in your layout XML.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce is with using the Nav Graph or is that the old way? What would I be able to use for a container?

Comment: Jetpack Navigation uses replace + addToBackStack which will destroy and recreate your view, but it's the same thing people generally use. If the Fragment doesn't retain its position, then you have a state restoration bug in your code.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I see what you mean! Yeah, I just don't want the current Fragment to recreate the whole view. Just want it to start from the onStart() function instead of the onCreateView() when going back to it.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible at this time afaik. `setMaxLifecycle(CREATED)` also triggers `onDestroyView`, while `setMaxLifecycle(STARTED)` only triggers `onPause` but not `onStop`.

Comment: "Yeah, I just don't want the current Fragment to recreate the whole view" - this isn't how you should be thinking about Android development. Working around the correct way of doing things is not a productive use of your time. Just make sure your fragment restores its state correctly.

Comment: @ianhanniballake yeah you're right. I just want save the user's list and position in a RecyclerView which gets refreshed for now. I guess I can save those in User Preferences

Comment: Those are already saved if you've written your fragment correctly. If you open a new question to fix those issues, feel free to include a link to it here and I can certainly take a look at that question.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I think its because in the Fragment's ```onCreateView()``` function, I init the RecyclerView with the primary list, so it basically reloads the list as new again. So my thought process was to avoid calling the ```onCreateView()``` in order to just have it in the same spot. Thanks for the responses btw!